# In Django, after user login if click on any link he gets logged out

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, session, logout

Previously it was working fine. But now as long as user click on any link he is getting logged out. Does any know why it's happening? It's not issue with code as I didn't even change a single line and it was working finely. 
Update -this morning when I was rechecking it started to work finely without any issue but what was the problem I am not clear .
My project guide suggested that it was probably session cookie problem as it was working fine with different browser . But how to prevent this??

Comment: Does this behaviour happen on a range of different browsers?

Comment: Where is the site hosted? Was there any change on this? Trace the traffic, the login session is very likely a cookie. Is that really set by the server? Is it sent back by the client?